# JSONP alert parsererror

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$.ajax({
    type:           "GET",
    dataType:       "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback:  "jsoncallback",
    //async: false ,
    data: 
    {
        // some data here

    },
    url: "http://mydomain.com/checkRequest.php",
    success: function(data){

    alert("123");

            alert(data.data.NameA);

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    }
});// end of ajax
```

I can get the following string from the URL below,

```
([{
        "data": {
            "Rate": "",
            "RoleA": "Student",
            "NameA": "studentD",
            "RoleB": "Tutor",
            "NameB": "tutorB",
            "Give": "0",
            "Get": "1",
            "Accept": "0",
            "RateCounter": ""
        }
    }
]);
```

`http://mydomain.com/checkRequest.php?callback=jsoncallback&nameB=tutorB&roleB=Tutor&get=1&roleA=Student&nameA=studentD&give=0&_=1364082750444`

however, it alerts `parsererror`. May I ask where's going wrong?

If I delete  `jsonpCallback:  "jsoncallback",`  and change `URL` to url: `"http://mydomain.com/checkRequest.php?jsoncallback=?",` there is no parsererror, but it does not able to `alert(data.data.NameA);`

Comment: You should really be using the console when working with objects, and not alerts. That way you could see what's really going on, and you could even see what the parseerror was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the `jsonp` option rather than `jsonpCallback`:

```
$.ajax({
    type:           "GET",
    dataType:       "jsonp",
    jsonp:          "jsoncallback",
    // ...
});
```

`jsonp` sets the ***name*** of the parameter and would match with your other example:

```
url: "http://mydomain.com/checkRequest.php?jsoncallback=?",
```

With `jsonpCallback`, you're instead setting the ***value***, resulting in a URL that contains `callback=jsoncallback`. The server doesn't appear to expect this and ends up responding without a function name:

```
([{...}]);
```

vs. something like:

```
jQuery191_etc([{...}]);
```

---

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **jsonp**
>
> Override the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value
>   will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part of the
>   query string in the url. So `{jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'}` would result in
>   `'onJSONPLoad=?'` passed to the server. [...]

> **jsonpCallback**
>
> Specify the callback function name for a JSONP request. This value
>   will be used instead of the random name automatically generated by
>   jQuery. [...]